# How to post data from partial view to different controller and validate model in Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have one main form and has child form like this

```
@using(Html.beginform("A","ABC")){

 @Html.Partial("PA", Model.A)

<input type=submit />

}
```

And a partial view has field like this

```
@using(html.beginform("PA",B)){

   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.abc, new { Class = "form-control", placeholder = "abc" })

<input type=submit/>

}
```

Here issue is that child partial view submit button point to parent form controller action so i am not able to post back data to server and validate model.

Comment: you are making nested forms which is not valid..

Comment: Place `@Html.Partial("PA", Model.A)` outside closing brackets of `@using(Html.beginform("A","ABC")){`